# How would you approach isolating a dependency resolver to one area in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-areas

In the recent spirit of isolating stuff and plugging it in via NuGet, does anyone have an idea about how you'd limit a dependency resolver to just one area in MVC3? It's easy enough to keep views and controllers limited to an area, but unless I'm not seeing an obvious hook, it looks like setting an IDependencyResolver is something that unavoidably has global scope. I'd like to limit it to just one area.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IDependencyResolver` is global by design. If you want to vary behavior by area, you should look at the various *Activator types and interfaces that can make decisions based on context objects.

What specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: Imagine you have a forum implemented as an area. It uses Ninject. You also have some kind of photo gallery implemented as an area. It uses Structure Map. In other words, you're taking all kinds of open source projects to quickly Frankenstein a site together.

Comment: Areas is effectively a routing feature, not a security or configuration feature. Based on this fact, each of your areas needs to provide their own way of doing isolated DI (the *Activator classes providing one such way).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the Common Service Locator for this.  Basically each area could setup up the CSL for their specific container.

You will probably need to create an adapter between the dependency resolver or forgo it altogether and strictly use the CSL.

In general I am not a proponent of using the CSL in a line of business app.  It's intent is to make it easier for open source components that use DI (like MassTransit) easier to integrate into line of business apps.  This might be an exception however.

Also, look into the mvccontrib portable areas.  It's designed for this type of thing.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do sounds like a bad idea. The point of dependency injection is so you can isolate specific dependencies and not have your code care where they come from.

If you're trying to restrict some objects or classes to a certain MVC area, configure your dependency injector to call the proper ones at the right time.

Some more details about what you're trying to do will help generate better answers.

Comment: It's not a bad idea at all. If you want to piece together a site made from several apps, and each use their own DI containers, it's exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Jeff: The idea of dependency injection is that the dependency resolution is done at one place. For instance you use the resolver to create a `ValidateUserController` that has a dependency on the `EnableUserCommand` that has dependencies on the `IMailSender` and `IUnitOfWorkFactory` that has a dependency on a `IDataMapper` etc etc. The resolver will create that graph at once. When you use different apps that already have a depedency on a particular framework, than you have not much choice. You need those frameworks. What could work for some apps is route those frameworks to the fx of choice.

Comment: I know what the design pattern is. Look around, you might find examples of me using it in open source projects. I don't think you're listening to my point about getting different apps living together, each their own discreet architecture.